# DnD not working well in Chrome, no image while dragging

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webkit, chromium

Initially I found event.dataTransfer.setDragImage not working in chrome, such as in the following example.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=html5-59.htm

Later I found that the cursor is always the same no matter what I was dragging. This is not the case in Firefox.

http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

In the above example, when open in Firefox, the item is moving with the mouse while I drag it. But in chrome, only a cursor is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you disabled all effects under Performance Options in System settings.

But Firefox can show the correct image even if all effects are disabled.

Except this, I have no reason to use old ways of drag and drop.
Is there a way to overcome this? I also encounter this problem.